# Images not showing up on localhost

Tags: wordpress

I installed WordPress on my localhost (Windows 10 + XAMPP): I copied a new WordPress folder to htdocs, and installed WordPress. Everything worked fine, but 1 day later and images are gone. I didn't do anything. Yetserday I installed a theme, and the demo images worked fine, now no images are showing. I did not even edit the site.. they just disappeared. why?

Comment: Welcome to SO! No offense, but are you aware that there is a [WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) community for developers and admins at StackExchange?